# Error: HTTP Error: 400, hosting.rewrites[0] is not exactly one from [subschema 0 ],[subschema 1]

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have created a function and when I build the project after including the function in firebase.json , I get an error as mentioned.

```
 {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You were sending source to both a function and destination, should be either one, not both.

Answer (score 1):

Your nodejs file needs to have a get route that will be used as the entry point for the rest of your methods.

```
"source: "**"
```

needs an actual route.

for my apps i use init

```
app.get('/init',function(req, res){
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => console.log(__dirname));
})
```

therefore my source needs to be

```
"source: "/init"
```

For more information checkout: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOeioOKUKI8

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Either form your own complete answer or delete this altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I removed the destination in the rewrite section and it worked. I am not sure if i am missing anything else to get the request pass through functions